# How to fix error: Deprecated: Required parameter

Tags: php, pdo

How to fix the function error?

> **Deprecated: Required parameter $orderfield follows optional parameter $where in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\includes\functions\functions.php on line 8**

```
function getAllFrom($field, $table, $where = NULL, $and = NULL, $orderfield, $ordering = "DESC") {
    global $con;
    $getAll = $con->prepare("SELECT $field FROM $table $where $and ORDER BY $orderfield $ordering");
    $getAll->execute();
    $all = $getAll->fetchAll();
    return $all;
}
```

```
<?php
$allItems = getAllFrom('*', 'items', 'where Approve = 1', '', 'Item_ID');
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
    echo '<div class="thumbnail item-box">';
    echo '<span class="price-tag">$' . $item['Price'] . '</span>';
    echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" alt="" />';
    echo '<div class="caption">';
    echo '<h3><a href="items.php?itemid='. $item['Item_ID'] .'">' . $item['Name'] .'</a></h3>';
    echo '<p>' . $item['Description'] . '</p>';
    echo '<div class="date">' . $item['Add_Date'] . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe give the variable `orderfield` a value like `$orderfield = ''`. But to be honest, querying your database like this feels very wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function has required paramaters after optional ones...

`getAllFrom($field, $table, $where = NULL, $and = NULL, $orderfield, $ordering = "DESC")`

`$where` `$and` are both optional (because they have default values). `$orderfield` is required because it doesn't have a default value.

So the order should be:

`getAllFrom($field, $table, $orderfield, $where = NULL, $and = NULL, $ordering = "DESC")`

Order make `$where` and `$and` required too...

`getAllFrom($field, $table, $where, $and, $orderfield, $ordering = "DESC")`

If you need a "non-breaking" solution you could do something like...

```php
function getAllFrom($field, $table, $where = NULL, $and = NULL, $orderfield = null, $ordering = "DESC") {

    if ( $orderfield === null ) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Parameter 5 of getAllFrom function is required.' );
    }

    global $con;

    $getAll = $con->prepare("SELECT $field FROM $table $where $and ORDER BY $orderfield $ordering");

    $getAll->execute();

    $all = $getAll->fetchAll();

    return $all;

}
```

Comment: the throw is just an additional layer of code obfuscation imnsho ... best to fix the signature, and track every caller and make certain they respect the signature.  A good IDE helps :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Agreed!